# When should a closed question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The closure rate of questions is seem as a problem by some on Skeptics.SE. The answer usually given (link usually and given to past questions) is that a question being closed is a "pause" state, so the question can be reopened. If that is the case, then questions should be reopened when possible.

**If a question is closed for a specific reason and that issue is resolved, the question should be reopened.**

It is sometimes said that such decisions should be left to the community to reopen, although that it not the right attitude.

More than half the users on this site don't have enough reputation to ask for questions to be reopened. Out of those that do many are not frequently active.

In part because of this I think closing questions should be done with restraint. If there is a notable claim and the question is not too vague, if the question has resolved the issue for which it was closed, then it should be reopened.

*Users should not have to justify their question to be reopened after the issue for which there question was closed. If a moderator doesn't have a specific reason why the question should be closed, then it should be reopened.*

**Put simply, if the question in it's current state would not have been closed initially, it should not remain closed.**

Comment: Please stop making new meta posts about the same question, there should be at most one meta question for discussing a specific post on the main site, not half a dozen.

Comment: @Fabian I'm asking when a question should be reopened after being closed, not asking why a question was closed. How is this an exact duplicate? Also the question is substantially different now that the other question no longer applies.

Comment: Two thirds of this post are about one specific question of yours that already has one meta post about it.

Comment: @Fabian then I would like to delete the other question. Nothing in that question bears relevance to the question I am asking about here.

Comment: @Fabian edited out most of the example, it's hardly a duplicate...

Comment: I've removed the example completely and reopened. Though I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this post, if a question is edited to conform to the site's standards it usually is reopened by a mod. I don't see what you want us to do different.

Comment: @Fabian it's why I was using the example. A question has been editied to conform to standards but remains closed. If the question were posted today anew it would not be closed, so it should not remain closed. That's the point.

Answer (score 3):

A question will be reopened once **one mod** or **five high rep users** agree that it is fixed and suitable.

This is the SE-wide criterion for what "fixed" means, therefore discussion on this criterion pertains on meta.SO and not here.

Comment: [Removed comments] Please *consider* adding an answer if you have a better solution, or simply down vote if you disagree.