# Should the reputation for close/reopen be reduced?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we adjust the privilege/reputation levels?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/can-we-adjust-the-privilege-reputation-levels)

Because Skeptics is out of beta, approximately 30 users have enough privileges to close or re-open questions. Considering how heavily used this feature is, I think this is insufficient - it means that one sixth of the eligible populace is required to re-open a question unless a diamond mod is involved.

Should the reputation requirement be lowered?

[When should a closed question be reopened?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/when-should-a-closed-question-be-reopened) touches upon this topic, but has been interpreted at least in part as a complaint about a specific question, and I think that question was asked before skeptics left beta.

Comment: Probably should be an answer but I'm in a hurry... Users who can't vote to close/open can still flag :-)

Comment: The fact that there a previous discussion on meta about changing reputation level doesn't mean that it makes so sense to discuss the topic again. The community changed quite a bit since then and you have less people who vote on open/closing questions than you had in the past.